# Access api-server Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver

I have a kubernetes api-server IP address and im trying to check if it's possible to use kubectl to access the environment when you have only api server ip address and not the master/node address.

Thanks!

Comment: what is your definition of "api-server IP address" in contrast to "master address"? More importantly, what **error message** are you getting when you try?

Comment: I’m not getting an error, but I wanted to know if it’s possible to login cluster using the api server external ip and not through the master. I found out that it’s not possible and I must connect to the master

Answer (score 1):

It Isn't possible connecting straight to the api-server using kube without using the Master. Plus in order to login you must have the user, pass and certificate in most cases.
The scenario will be: connecting into the environment using the master than all the commands executed in kube will automaticall query the api-server.